# for loop on vector, return a single index always

Tags: c++, for-loop, vector

I'm trying to reproduce a problem to ask it in SO! but the sample that I want to create, have a problem itself!

As you see below, I wrote a simple program that receives 5 element from user and put them inside a `u_char` vector. After that I'm trying to print the vector's members.

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <vector>
  #include <stdint.h>
  #include <netinet/ip.h>
  #include <netinet/tcp.h>
  #include <netinet/ether.h>

  int main(){
      std::vector<u_char*> packets;
      u_char packet[10];
      std::cout << "Receiving Values :\n";
      for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
          std::cin >> packet;
          packets.push_back(packet);
      }

      std::cout << "\n\n\nPrinting Values :\n";                                                                                                                        
      for(auto p : packets){
          std::cout << p << "\n";
          std::cout << "------------\n";
      }
      return 0;
  }
```

And this is the output:

```
me@me-MS-7693:~/Desktop/test$ ./a.out 
Receiving Values :
aaaa
b  
ccccc
ddd
ggggggg



Printing Values :
ggggggg
------------
ggggggg
------------
ggggggg
------------
ggggggg
------------
ggggggg
------------
```

Why in the output, I receive the last member only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because you push a pointer to the same array into a `vector` of pointers. This has two consequences:

- All entries are the same, and equal to the last entry, because the pointer is always the same; the data does not get copied into the vector, only the pointer, and the pointer is always the same, because there is only one array `packet[10]`.
- The element of the vector become invalid as soon as the local variable representing array goes out of scope. This is not an issue for your sample program, because you have only one function, but in a program that does its reading in a separate function this could lead to undefined behavior.

To fix this problem you need to change the type of vector's elements to something that has a copy functionality, e.g. `std::string`.

Answer (score 1):

because you've defined a vector or u_char * and you're pushing the same reference over and over, meaning that you get the last value in all vector cells.

Answer (score 1):

When `packets.push_back(packet);`, the pointer is copied as the element of `vector`, not the pointee. That means all of them are pointing to the same address. That's why you're getting the same result when you print out them as c-style string.

Using `std::string` like `std::vector<std::string>` will get the result you expect.